# How to create debian package for offline installation?

Tags: python, build, debian, package, ubuntu-10.04

Here, what I would like :
I want to develop debian package of my project for offline installation.
Project contains some dependency like python-lxml and etc. I have downloaded required packages from the different machine which have internet connectivity. now on another machine (which does not have internet connectivity), I would like to copy all required packages in "/var/cache/apt/archive" folder (from debian package installation) before the execution of control file. so when control file would be executed it could install dependent packages from the "/var/cache/apt/archive" folder instead of searching on internet.

What changes should I have to apply and In which file? or Is there any other suggestion for creating offline installation package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Amazing, just a few seconds ago I recommended `apt-offline` to a fellow stacker:

```
Description: offline apt package manager
 apt-offline is an Offline APT Package Manager
 .
 apt-offline can fully update and upgrade an APT based distribution without
 connecting to the network, all of it transparent to apt
 .
 apt-offline can be used to generate a signature on a machine (with no network).
 This signature contains all download information required for the apt database
 system. This signature file can be used on another machine connected to the
 internet (which need not be a Debian box and can even be running windows) to
 download the updates.
 The downloaded data will contain all updates in a format understood by apt and
 this data can be used by apt-offline to update the non-networked machine.
 .
 apt-offline can also fetch bug reports and make them available offline
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to know about apt-offline, I have read [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-offline.8.html) for more detail but I am still confuse, How can I use it in debian creation as I want all the process should be done from the debian package at installation.

Comment: Aha, that is indeed a different goal; for my new installations, I normally use the smallest "network install disc" I can find -- I really just want the kernel, a shell, and `apt-get`, so I can run `apt-get install i3 vim openssh-server irssi firefox ...` and whatever other programs I need. You could do the same, or look into using [`chef`](http://www.opscode.com/chef/), [`puppet`](http://www.puppetlabs.com/), or [FAI](http://wiki.debian.org/FAI) to manage deployments.